# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.SupportThreads'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server

Im trying to open my account on university website but im getting this error, help me to solve this problem because i dont have any idea about this.

[image: image of error]

Comment: Is that a website you developed ? The developer is trying to access a table that doesn't exist or doesn't have access to or using the incorrect schema or database.

Comment: No i didn't develop this website

Comment: Then Contact the university's IT team for them to fix this issue. This is not something wrong that you're doing yourself.